# A program that reads a text file and determines the most expensive purchase

Tags: credit-card

The program i need help with involves reading a .txt file that contains 
transactions from a credit card, example: groceries $50.36, gas $41.20, etc. and i need to find the most expensive item and print the name and the price of the item.I am having problems finding a way to get and tell which one is the most expensive. How do i read and grab the integers and compare them to the rest to see which is bigger?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Transcation {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter the directory of file: "); //ask for file
           String filename = console.nextLine();       //input directory of file

           File inputFile = new File(filename);        

           if(!inputFile.exists()){     //if it does not exist print error,end
               System.out.println("Transaction.txt not found");
               System.exit(0);
           }

           Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);  //reads and access the file
           String line;


                while(input.hasNext()){   //while its still has more lines loop
                    line = input.nextLine();    

                        //System.out.println(line); //prints the next line

                }         
          input.close();    //closes file

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's always a good idea to provide some code that shows what you've attempted. From what you pasted, I don't see anything that's trying to do anything with the numbers? Also note, you said read `integers` when prices are not integers as they have cents.

Comment: Integers? Your prices seem to be float/doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split string by `' '` into name and the value. Parse the value to `double`.

Like so:

```
String[] parts = yourStringFromFileLine.split( " " );

// access the parts
String name = parts[ 0 ]; // name if item
double price = Double.parseDouble( parts[ 1 ] ); // price of item
```

Save each line in a `Map` for name as `key` and the price as the `value`.

Like so:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
// add content to map
map.put( name , price );
```

When you have finished reading the file, iterate over the `Map` und find the highest `value` for the `key`.

Like so:

```
double tempPrice = 0.0;

for ( Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map ) {
    if ( entry.getValue() > tempPrice ) {
        tempPrice = entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

At the end `tempPrice` is the highest price of all the entries.

Hope this helps.